# How to use numpy.char.join?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy

A critical portion of my script relies on the concatenation of a large number of fixed-length strings. So I would like to use low-level [`numpy.char.join`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.join.html#numpy.char.join) function instead of the classical python build `str.join`.

However, I can't get it to work right:

```py
import numpy as np

# Example array.
array = np.array([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    ], dtype='<U1')

# Now I wish to get:
# array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='<U3')

# But none of these is successful :(
np.char.join('', array)
np.char.join('', array.astype('<U3'))
np.char.join(np.array(''), array.astype('<U3'))
np.char.join(np.array('').astype('<U3'), array.astype('<U3'))
np.char.join(np.array(['', '', '']).astype('<U3'), array.astype('<U3'))
np.char.join(np.char.asarray(['', '', '']).astype('<U3'), np.char.asarray(array))
np.char.asarray(['', '', '']).join(array)
np.char.asarray(['', '', '']).astype('<U3').join(array.astype('<U3'))
```

.. and my initial array is always left unchanged.

What am I missing here?
What's numpy's most efficient way to concatenate each line of a large 2D `<U1` array?

---

[EDIT]: Since performance is a concern, I have benchmarked proposed solutions. But I still don't know how to call [`np.char.join`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.join.html#numpy.char.join) properly.

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from time import time

# Build up an array with many random letters
n_lines = int(1e7)
n_columns = 4
array = np.array(list(letters))[rd.randint(0, len(letters), n_lines * n_columns)]
array = array.reshape((n_lines, n_columns))

# One quick-n-dirty way to benchmark.
class MeasureTime(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.tic = time()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        toc = time()
        print(f"{toc-self.tic:0.3f} seconds")


# And test three concatenations procedures.
with MeasureTime():
    # Involves str.join
    cat = np.apply_along_axis("".join, 1, array)

with MeasureTime():
    # Involves str.join
    cat = np.array(["".join(row) for row in array])

with MeasureTime():
    # Involve low-level np functions instead.
    # Here np.char.add for example.
    cat = np.char.add(
        np.char.add(np.char.add(array[:, 0], array[:, 1]), array[:, 2]), array[:, 3]
    )
```

outputs

```
41.722 seconds
19.921 seconds
15.206 seconds
```

on my machine.

Would [`np.char.join`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.join.html#numpy.char.join) do better? How to make it work?

Comment: Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but: `np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 1, array)` is one option...

Comment: @JonClements Well, it is not if I believe this small benchmark I've added up to my post :P I think it's because it still relies on `str.join`. Any idea how to make `np.char.join` work instead?

Comment: All the `np.char` functions use the corresponding string methods.  They are no faster than iterating explicity on the strings.  `numpy` has 'low-level' numeric code, but no custom code for strings.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a speed tool.  It's a convenience when iterating on two (or more axes) of a 3d array, but that's it.  @JonClements

Comment: @hpaulj I would precisely expect `np.char.join` to run such "low-level numeric code" and be more efficient than `str.join`. Are you meaning that `np.char.join` internally calls `str.join`? :( Then why is `np.char.add` faster than `str.join`?

Comment: @iago-lito, according to [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.char.join.html), it "calls `str.join` element-wise"

Comment: @ForceBru Well, I am disappointed :( Maybe `np.char.add` is the best way to go in the end. Anyway, how am I supposed to use `np.char.join`? None of my attempts did join the array :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the original (3,3) array  (timings may scale differently):

The chained `np.char.add`:

```
In [88]: timeit np.char.add(np.char.add(arr[:,0],arr[:,1]),arr[:,2])                           
29 µs ± 223 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

An equivalent approach, using `object` dtype.  For python strings, '+' is a string join.

```
In [89]: timeit arr.astype(object).sum(axis=1)                                                 
14.1 µs ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For a list of strings, `''.join()` is supposed to be faster than string sum. Plus it lets you specify a 'delimiter':

```
In [90]: timeit np.array([''.join(row) for row in arr])                                        
13.8 µs ± 41.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Without the conversion back to array:

```
In [91]: timeit [''.join(row) for row in arr]                                                      
10.2 µs ± 15.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Better yet, use `tolist` to convert the array to a list of lists of strings:

```
In [92]: timeit [''.join(row) for row in arr.tolist()]                                         
1.01 µs ± 1.81 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

the list comprehension equivalent of the nested `np.char.add`:

```
In [97]: timeit [row[0]+row[1]+row[2] for row in arr.tolist()]                                 
1.19 µs ± 2.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`numpy` does not have low-level string code, at least not in the same sense that it has low-level compiled numeric code.  It still depends on Python string code, even if it calls it from the C-API.

====

Since the strings are `U1`, we can view them as `U3`:

```
In [106]: arr.view('U3')                                                                       
Out[106]: 
array([['abc'],
       ['def'],
       ['ghi']], dtype='<U3')
In [107]: arr.view('U3').ravel()                                                               
Out[107]: array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='<U3')
In [108]: timeit arr.view('U3').ravel()                                                        
1.04 µs ± 9.81 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

===

To use `np.char.join` we have to collect the rows into some sort of tuple, list, etc.  One way to do that is make an object dtype array, and fill it from the array:

```
In [110]: temp = np.empty(arr.shape[0], object)                                                
In [111]: temp                                                                                 
Out[111]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [112]: temp[:] = list(arr)                                                                  
In [113]: temp                                                                                 
Out[113]: 
array([array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1'),
       array(['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype='<U1'),
       array(['g', 'h', 'i'], dtype='<U1')], dtype=object)
In [114]: np.char.join('',temp)                                                                
Out[114]: array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='<U3')
```

or filling it with a list of lists:

```
In [115]: temp[:] = arr.tolist()                                                               
In [116]: temp                                                                                 
Out[116]: 
array([list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['d', 'e', 'f']),
       list(['g', 'h', 'i'])], dtype=object)
In [117]: np.char.join('',temp)                                                                
Out[117]: array(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], dtype='<U3')

In [122]: %%timeit  
     ...: temp = np.empty(arr.shape[0], object) 
     ...: temp[:] = arr.tolist() 
     ...: np.char.join('', temp) 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                                      
22.1 µs ± 69.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

====

To get a better idea of what `np.char.join` can do, compare it with `split`:

```
In [132]: temp                                                                                 
Out[132]: 
array([list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['d', 'e', 'f']),
       list(['g', 'h', 'i'])], dtype=object)
In [133]: b = np.char.join(',',temp)                                                           
In [134]: b                                                                                    
Out[134]: array(['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i'], dtype='<U5')
In [135]: np.char.split(b,',')                                                                 
Out[135]: 
array([list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['d', 'e', 'f']),
       list(['g', 'h', 'i'])], dtype=object)
```

Another way to apply `''.join` to the elements of the object array:

```
In [136]: np.frompyfunc(lambda s: ','.join(s), 1,1)(temp)                                      
Out[136]: array(['a,b,c', 'd,e,f', 'g,h,i'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Well, I am deeply disappointed that numpy doesn't have low-level handling of strings, but I am almost equally suprised that str.join was not the hot point here. So I guess I'm happy :) Thank you for that. Should I still wait for someone to answer the question of correct call to `np.char.join` before closing the topic?

Comment: `pandas`, which makes heavy use of `numpy` does not use the `numpy` string dtypes.  Instead it stores all strings as Python strings, with `object` dtype.  It has its own way of invoking string methods.

Comment: The `np.char` functions are applied on an element by element basis.  Thus `np.char.join` can only join strings in a tuple (or list or array).  `join` does not work on `rows` of the 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([''.join(row) for row in array])
```

is the pythonic way, using list comprehension then treating it as a numpy array.

Comment: This also uses `str.join` instead of `np.char.join`, which I have good reasons to think is less efficient :\ I've added a benchmark to my post ;)